# Adding git submodule into the root of the repository?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want to keep my Vim plugins up-to-date with git by using github repos as submodules with the help of [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen). Everything is well except pathogen itself.

For example, I have a repository in `~/.vim`, at pathogen's repo has `autoload` directory in its root: `<pathogen repo>/autoload`.

Is it possible to make a git submodule so that pathogen's `autoload` goes into `~/.vim`?

```
~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Clone the submodule into a subdirectory and *symlink* it's contents.

For pathogen, I also [explicitly blacklisted](https://github.com/tlvince/vim-config/commit/19146d4c6f0a0e4c2c96e0756a4c1d5092467b19) itself (in the bundle directory) to prevent it from self-sourcing.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, except pathogen is outside `bundle` directory. This doesn't work on Windows (which I don't use, anyway), so I was waiting for a somewhat portable answer to appear.

Comment: I believe you can create a symbolic link in Windows: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/

Answer (score 10):

You can't have a submodule at the root of your repository because both .git folder would conflicts.

You must create your submodule in a subfolder.