# Git Submodules and packages

Tags: java, git, package, git-submodules

I'm new with Git submodules.

I have the following structure in my project:

```
src/main/com/feature1
src/main/com/feature2
src/main/com/feature3
src/main/com/commonFeature
```

I have the same structure for the tests, but under the following package:

```
src/test/com/feature1 ...
```

As the package "commonFeature" is something that I want to reuse for other projects, I would like to create a Git submodule for it. I'm thinking about the following options to reorganize my packages structure:

```
src/main/com/commonFeature/main/
src/main/com/commonFeature/test/
```

or

```
src/commonFeature/main
src/commonFeature/test
```

Then I would keep my other packages project as before under:

```
src/main/com/feature1 ....
```

What would be the best way?

Answer (score 0):

A few considerations on your question:

```
src/main/com/commonFeature/main/
src/main/com/commonFeature/test/
```

Is not consistent with the description of your initial repository, so you'll probably have to fix a lot of broken links.

```
src/commonFeature/main
src/commonFeature/test
```

This as well is not consistent, and without any additional knowledge on `/main/com/` it is an alternative just as good as the first one.

Seen that in both cases you'll have to fix a lot of links, you should approach the problem thinking in a different way.

You [cannot add a git submodule in the root of your git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5232887/2125110). This forces you to move all the common libs to a new folder. If that is the case, just think of your new folder like this:

```
/._
  |_ /.git
  |_ /main
  |_ /test
```

You'll have to add it somewhere in your current, where depends on the meaning of `/src`, `/main`, `/com`. Anyway you look at it you'll have to fix broken links.

An alternative to preserve your current tree and have another repository would be to [clone two repositories in the same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17313342/2125110). This is tricky, and is a workaround to the limitation posed by SubModules.